# Implementing multi provider authentication in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, omniauth

I am working in a project that provides authentication with multiple providers such as Facebook, Twitter, Google, Foursquare. Which gem is suitable for all these providers? I think i can use Omniauth. But i want to know the difference between OAuth and Omniauth.. Any resources for that means let me know..

Thanks..

Comment: OAuth is a generic means to authenticate with a service or API (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth).  OmniAuth is a gem made to easily handle authentication with all different kinds of web services like FB, Twitter, etc. for you (https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki)

Comment: Hi.. Could please explain some more about OAuth? Then how it differs from Omniauth? Thank u..

Comment: Sites like Twitter implement OAuth as an authentication system to allow third-party apps to access their API.  OmniAuth talks to the OAuth system and authenticates you with sites like Twitter.  OmniAuth essentially abstracts away all the authentication that your website would have to do with Facebook, Twitter, Foursquare, etc. so that it's all very easy to do.  So you use OmniAuth to easily authenticate with all those sites that have OAuth.  Read the links I gave for more info

Comment: It is useful.. Thank u.. I will learn more about this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ryan Bates did some excellent screencasts on this subject:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth